# Get data from nested object

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that returns a nested object,

```
console.log (moviesTrailer)
```

Returns,

```
[Object]
  0: Object
    backdrop: "/LvmmDZxkTDqp0DX7mUo621ahdX.jpg"
    cast: null
    created_at: "2016-01-08T17:21:32.112Z"
    crew: null
    id: 35
    image: "/bIuOWTtyFPjsFDevqvF3QrD1aun.jpg"
    movie_id: "10195"
    release_date: "2011-04-28"
    title: "Thor"
    updated_at: "2016-01-08T17:21:32.112Z"
    user_id: null
    __proto__: Objectlength: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

How can I reach data such as id, or title?

I've tried

```
console.log (moviesTrailer.object[0].id)
```

and

```
console.log (moviesTrailer.data[0].id)
```

but this returns a `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: moviestrailer is returning an array of objects, denoted by `[Object]`. You have to reference the index first

Comment: @corvid imo no. `moviesTrailer` is an object with a property called `0`, instead of an array with index `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moviesTrailer[0].id` should work.

`moviesTrailer` is an object with a property named `0` with a value of a reference to an object with these properties:

```
backdrop: "/LvmmDZxkTDqp0DX7mUo621ahdX.jpg"
cast: null
created_at: "2016-01-08T17:21:32.112Z"
crew: null
id: 35
image: "/bIuOWTtyFPjsFDevqvF3QrD1aun.jpg"
movie_id: "10195"
release_date: "2011-04-28"
title: "Thor"
updated_at: "2016-01-08T17:21:32.112Z"
user_id: null
__proto__: Objectlength: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

demo [here](http://jsbin.com/wihojevuna/1/edit?js,console,output).